# Is the Earth round?

Tags: earth, planets

Imagine you are a common man and want to prove that the Earth is Round, how would you prove it without any mathematical derivation or without the theory of the ships.

Comment: You can't, because the Earth is not a sphere.  For that matter, how can you define a sphere without math?

Comment: Ok i would like to change the question sphere into Round.

Comment: If the sun has set while you are laying on the ground, and you stand up, you see it again. That's a sort of proof.

Comment: Related to what jinawee said, standing on a taller structure allows you to see further than standing on the ground.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the theory of the ships?

Comment: nivag, suppose there are two ships named A and B. when you are at the poles(north or south) in the deck of A only the topmost part of B is visible to you and vice-versa.

Comment: The answer is much easier than any of this. Simply log on to the internet and type "Earth" into google. The first link will probably contain a written proof as well as some pictures from space. Anyone that isn't willing to take a picture from space as proof Earth is round probably won't be convinced by any of these other methods either.

Comment: Well Jim, Physics is all about believing. I dont think anyone is 100% sure whether the light is a wave or matter but still we believe. We can just assume, Physics requires proof but not always. I do not want to be somebody who thinks Earth is round because Google says it and contains pictures. Tomorrow if I need to integrate log x then I dont think want to surf the net to get the answer. Lastly i was not here to get the answers I was here to know the thousand different ways to get to the answers. Thank you.

Comment: going\ into space?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is framing physics as a belief system. Therefore it belongs in philosophy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just look at [how people actually did it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_geodesy). ;) Measuring shadow length at the same time at different places, comparing horizons (as also suggested in comments),... Also have a look [at this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_Earth#Summary_of_evidence_for_a_spherical_earth), some of which are down to earth methods. ;)

By the way, there are easy ways to prove that the earth is rotating, like the [Foucault Pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum), as well.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you can see the horizon is an indication that the Earth is round. If the earth was flat on a clear day if you chose the right spot you should be able to see to the end of the Earth (or at least the nearest mountain range). From memory the distance you can see from ~1m above see level (think sitting in a lifeboat) is ~5km due to the curvature of the Earth.

For many reasons this is a somewhat unsatisfying logic. You could easily argue this effect is due to haze/atmospherics and you rarely have unobstructed views anyway.

A more convincing argument used by the ancient Greeks is to consider shadows case by a pole (or down a well if you want to be historically accurate). Near the equator on the summer solstice at noon the sun will be directly overhead and cast no shadow. At the same time at another town some distance away the sun still casts a shadow. If we assume that the sun is far away so the light beams are parallel then we can conclude the Earth must be curved. Furthermore if you are prepared to do some maths using the angles of the shadow and the distance between the two points you can calculate the circumference and diameter of the Earth as was done by [Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes) around 240 BC.

Comment: I would like to add, as the Earth stood between the moon and the sun, the different shapes of the moon were due to the shadow cast by the Earth and the shadows we observe are always a curve which would put forth that the Earth is round but the problem is that being a simple man, there would be no clear proof for me that the Earth stood between the Sun and the Moon.

Comment: Thank You Echsecutor and nivag, your answers were very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the Earth is round, look at sunset on clear days. The sky is bright after the Sun has gone below the horizon. If there are some clouds these are still lit by the sun and cast crisp shadows. If the Earth were flat, the sky and clouds would get dark at the same time and any shadows would grow more and more feint.

Comment: It could also be a torus according to your analysis.